# JQuery Setting inline attribute in Grand children input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm in ASP.NET MVC. I need to modify an input tag with JQuery to set placeholder="Something"

I have these tags in a form

```
<div id="searchbox" class="SearchBox SearchInterface state 
ComponentState QueryController Debug">

    <div>
        <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" 
        class="QueryBox" form="dummy-form">
    </div> 
</div>
```

I have tried many things such as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchbox > div > input").prop('placeholder', 'Search');
});
```

But It's always like it can't find the input tag.

What's wrong with that and how I can do that ?

Thanks,

Comment: does searchbox div has a closing tag after the inner div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is working:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/9dRc8/
Seams you are missing a closing tag for the input or something like this.

Comment: Problem is I can't modify the input because it is autogenerated..
Maybe i'll do something with JQuery and .html() method.
And I'm in a form so I should be ok http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: can't you edit the code which generates the input to call a function to edit the placeholder? tell me how it is autogenerated may be I can help